# ffmpeg -hls_init_time -hls_time not working together?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am genarating an `m3u8` file with:

```
ffmpeg -i Sample2.avi \
    -hls_init_time 1 \
    -hls_time 10 \
    -f hls \
    -hls_list_size 0 \
    -hls_segment_filename 'partial_file%04d.ts' \
    -s 480x270 \
    out.m3u8
```

It seems that when I use `-hls_time 10` the segments are approx 10 seconds each. However, when I add `-hls_init_time 1` all segments are generated with length approx 1 sec.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:2.035367,
partial_file0000.ts
#EXTINF:1.101100,
partial_file0001.ts
#EXTINF:5.372033,
partial_file0002.ts
#EXTINF:1.267933,
partial_file0003.ts
#EXTINF:2.802800,
partial_file0004.ts
#EXTINF:0.867533,
partial_file0005.ts
```

I want only the first segment to be 1 second, and other segments to be 10 seconds.

I went through the documents [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-5) and I guess I am doing as mentioned in the doc.

**What am I missing ?**

Answer (score 6):

> **hls_init_time**
>
> After the *initial playlist is filled* `ffmpeg` will cut segments at duration equal to `hls_time`

You have `-hls_list_size 0` which means the playlist will contain *all the  segments* and it will get filled only once at the end.

That's why it never gets to use the `hls_time` value.

The solution is to use a playlist size larger than `0`. That means the first `hls_list_size` segments will have a duration of `1s`.

Comment: If i use "-hls_time 10" alone the m3u8/playlist file is created after 10 seconds. That is why i was thinking "-hls_list_size 1", which will create playlist immediately after 1 second and NOT 10 sec. Additionally, i intent to keep all the segments inside playlist so that user can seek back in time. Is it possible to achieve the both cases?

Comment: It doesn't matter when the playlist is written as you're encoding a video-on-demand and not a real-time stream. It will output as fast as your system allows.

Comment: Actually it takes couple of seconds. By that time the player shows error that it can not find playlist. Although, i handled it in player to retry after 3 seconds but i don't think its the elegant way.

Comment: You must encode it prior to making it available to the player.